# Inverting axis of matplotlib 3D plot ruins ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'll use the official Matplotlib 3.1.0 [example code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) for a 3D scatter plot:

```
# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    '''
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    '''
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

n = 100

# For each set of style and range settings, plot n random points in the box
# defined by x in [23, 32], y in [0, 100], z in [zlow, zhigh].
for m, zlow, zhigh in [('o', -50, -25), ('^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zlow, zhigh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

It plots the following image:

[image]

Now I'd like to invert the plotting order of the Y axis. I tried adding `ax.invert_yaxis()` after the for-loop that populates the plot, which does nothing. Adding the line after `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` does invert the plot itself as it should, but it messes up the ticks along the y axis:

[image]

Am I doing it wrong or could it be a bug? (I know that I can pass the data in an inverted array, but I feel that solution would be less clean).

Comment: Adding `ax.invert_yaxis()` **outside and after** the for loop works fine for me and reverses the order of the y-axis ticks. In the scatter points, you hardly notice the difference but look at the tick values to see the difference

Comment: @Sheldore Interesting, are you using version 3.1.0?

Comment: No, I am still on 2.2.2. ;) Some issue with 3+ in your case, it seems

Comment: Xref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14577

Answer (score 0):

The bug with the ruined ticks no longer appears in Matplotlib 3.5.0, but instead another bug is present causing `ax.invert_yaxis()` to actually invert the x axis while imposing the limits of the y axis:
[image: output with matplotlib 3.5.0]

This is reported here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21369

There is a workaround that actually does invert the y axis. Instead of `ax.invert_yaxis()`, use

```py
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax.set_ylim(ylim[::-1])
```

While this code freezes the y ticks, it does succeed at properly inverting the y axis, and should thus do in many applications. Just set axis limits and ticks positions before inverting the y axis and this should not bother you.

[image: output with matplotlib 3.5.0 and workaround]